# Create RESTAPI in laravel5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4

I am trying to create a RESTAPI in laravel5.4. so i wrote all the code. i defined my route files in `api.php`. when i run in the postman, it's not working. then i changed my route files in `web.php`. and then i run that in postman again. then it's working. why it's not working in `api.php` file ?

We have to define our roue files in `api.php` or `web.php` files?

Please help me. i am just confused.

Here is my roue file example:(api.php)

```
Route::get('sample-restful-apis', function()
{
    return array(
      1 => "expertphp",
      2 => "demo"
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define route file in web.php.

this route define in web.php file with array file and direct `sample-restful-apis` type in browser get the response

```
Route::get('sample-restful-apis', function()
{
    return array(
      1 => "expertphp",
      2 => "demo"
    );
});
```

Comment: Hello pratik, could you please elaborate a bit more and show the differences between the answer you proposed and the question ?

Comment: no more difference ..but you can only your code put in web.php file. your right but not define route in api.php

Answer (score 1):

Please try with /api in url, because api urls automatically have api prefix.
In your example  /api/sample-restful-apis.

Answer (score 0):

1. in routes/api.php, create all routes for apis.
2. create folder named v1 into app/Http/Controllers/Api.  put your required controllers into it.
3. for example, you want to get id type values, then first create route for that.

   `Route::get('/getidtype', 'Api\V1\UsersController@getIdtype');`  like this.
4. create or use created controller like UsersController.php. create function for return response like that

   ```
   public function getIdtype(Request $request){
           $idtypes = IdType::get();
           if(sizeOf($idtypes) > 0){
               echo "ID Types:";
               return $idtypes;
           }else{
               echo "No IdType Exist";
   ```

   }
       }
5. call this function at api tool or at web address like `http://localhost:8000/api/getidtype`

you will get your desired response. keep enjoy.

Comment: create group  at api.php like  Route::group(['middleware' => 'api', 'as' => 'api.'], function () {

Comment: for post method, pass variable like https://localhost:8000/api/changepassword?userid=10004